# AlertDialog with EditText with InputType email - Android

Tags: java, android, email, android-edittext, alert

I'm creating alert dialog with one EditText. I want that EditText to have input type email. This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setMessage("Enter your email");

final EditText email = new EditText(this);
email.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
email.setHint("Email...");

alert.setView(email);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

alert.show();
```

I also set Hint to that EditText and it's work, but input type does't work.....Any suggestion?

Comment: does your `EditText`show up?

Comment: yes and it show up. Also hint works.... but input type nop :/

Comment: don't forget your i18n stuff ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add below code to make it work :

```
email.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT 
          | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

See [`InputType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html). `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS` is just a variation basically that you add to the `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` flag. It somehow makes sense.

Comment: Thanks..it works, but can I ask you why I need to add InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |?
BTW I also need to add InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | if i want numeric EditText?

Comment: dont you actually have to create the builder first and then show it??